# Django Haystack and Woosh not working on web requests but working on django shell on production server

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh

On my production server, I'm not getting any search results with haystack when I search through the webpage, but it builds indexes correctly and I can retrieve results using the haystack api on the django shell.

No exceptions are being thrown, I just get no results at all.

On my local server everything works fine.

The only discernible difference is that the production server is using fcgi where as the local server is using wsgi.

I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on.  Any ideas?

Comment: What are the permissions on your search index folder? Your shell session is running as whatever user you are, but your wsgi session is probably running as another user - possibly uwsgi or something. If that user can't read your whoosh index folder, it'll fail.

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman.  I was sure I tried that - I had the directory 777'ed but changing it to be owned by apache.  That alone didn't resolve the issue.  I moved 
`import haystack
haystack.autodiscover()`
from search_sites.py to urls.py and the search started to work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by owning the search index directory to apache and moving:

```
import haystack
haystack.autodiscover()
```

from search_sites.py to urls.py

I still don't fully understand why the search is now working but I'm glad it is!

Comment: have you modified the haystack_site_conf to this `HAYSTACK_SITE_CONF = 'urls'` ?